# Blazor Server-Side Recursive Component over-memory consumption

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have this ChainableSelect component which is select and based on that it generates another ChainableSelect and on and on.
I noticed that if i changed the selection like around 7~10 times
memory consumption starts to rise without stopping causing my laptop to freeze

#### To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Using this version of ASP.NET Core '3.0' release
2. Run this code

```
 public class ChainableSelect<TEntity> : InputableBaseComponent where TEntity : DbModel
    {
        [Parameter]
        public IChainableSelectDataFetcher<TEntity> DataFetcher { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public string FilterText { get; set; } = "";
        [Parameter]
        public bool IsBusy { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public bool FilterChanged { get; set; } = true;
        [Parameter]
        public string ParentPropertyName { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public TEntity ParentEntity { get; set; }

        TEntity _localParentEntity;
        IViewProperty _localViewProperty;

        ReadOnlyObservableCollection<TEntity> _entities { get; set; }

        bool _updateEntities = true;

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            base.OnInitialized();
            _localViewProperty = ViewPropertyFactory.CreateEmptyProperty("", null);
        }

        protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        {
            await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
            if (DataFetcher != null)
            {
                if (_localParentEntity != ParentEntity || ParentEntity == null || FilterChanged)
                {
                    _entities = await DataFetcher.GetDescendents(ParentEntity, ParentPropertyName);
                    _updateEntities = false;
                }
                _localViewProperty.PropertyValue = null;
                FilterChanged = true;
                StateHasChanged();
            }
            _localParentEntity = ParentEntity;
        }

        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            if (_entities == null)
                return;
            if (_entities.Count == 0)
                return;

            var seq = 0;
            base.BuildRenderTree(builder);


            builder.OpenElement(seq, "input");
            builder.AddAttribute(seq, "class", "form-control form-control-sm dropdown-input bg-white");
            builder.AddAttribute(seq, "value", _localViewProperty.PropertyValue ?? "--SELECT--");
            builder.AddAttribute(seq, "readonly", "readonly");
            builder.AddAttribute(seq, "onfocus", "document.getElementById('" + Id + "').style.zIndex=1000");
            builder.CloseElement();

            builder.OpenElement(++seq, "div");
            builder.AddAttribute(seq, "class", "dropdown-div border");
            builder.AddAttribute(seq, "onmouseover", "document.getElementById('" + Id + "').style.zIndex=1000");
            builder.AddAttribute(seq, "onmouseout", "document.getElementById('" + Id + "').style.zIndex=1");

            builder.OpenElement(++seq, "div");
            builder.AddAttribute(seq, "class", "p-1 m-1 bg-white");

            builder.OpenElement(++seq, "input");
            builder.AddAttribute(seq, "class", "form-control form-control-sm");
            builder.AddAttribute(seq, "oninput", new Action<ChangeEventArgs>(OnFilterChanged));
            builder.CloseElement();

            builder.OpenElement(++seq, "hr");
            builder.CloseElement();

            builder.CloseElement();

            builder.OpenElement(++seq, "a");
            builder.AddAttribute(seq, "onclick", new Action(() => OnSelect(null)));
            builder.AddContent(seq, "None");
            builder.CloseElement();

            if (_entities != null)
                foreach (var _entity in _entities)
                {
                    if (!_entity.ToString().Contains(FilterText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        continue;
                    builder.OpenElement(++seq, "a");
                    builder.AddAttribute(seq, "onclick", new Action(() => OnSelect(_entity)));
                    if (_entity == _localViewProperty.PropertyValue)
                        builder.AddAttribute(seq, "class", "selected");
                    builder.AddContent(seq, _entity.ToString());
                    builder.CloseElement();
                }

            builder.CloseElement();
            builder.CloseElement();
            FilterChanged = false;

            if (_localViewProperty.PropertyValue != null && _localViewProperty.PropertyValue != ParentEntity)
            {
                builder.OpenComponent<ChainableSelect<TEntity>>(++seq);
                builder.AddAttribute(seq, "Parameters", Parameters);
                builder.AddAttribute(seq, "ParentEntity", ViewProperty.PropertyValue);
                builder.AddAttribute(seq, "ParentPropertyName", ParentPropertyName);
                builder.CloseComponent();
            }
        }

        private async void OnSelect(TEntity entity)
        {
            ViewProperty.PropertyValue = entity;
            _localViewProperty.PropertyValue = entity;
            FilterChanged = true;
            _updateEntities = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        protected override bool ShouldRender()
        {
            return !IsBusy && FilterChanged;
        }

        CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private async void OnFilterChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var _cancelationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            IsBusy = true;
            await Task.Delay(200, _cancelationToken).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (!_cancelationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    FilterText = e.Value.ToString();
                    FilterChanged = true;
                }
                IsBusy = false;
                InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            });
        }

    }
```

*ChainableDataFetcher*

```
public class ChainableEntityDataFetcher<TEntity> : IChainableSelectDataFetcher<TEntity> where TEntity : DbModel
    {
        public Func<TEntity, string, Task<ReadOnlyObservableCollection<TEntity>>> GetDescendents { get; set; }
        private readonly IDataAccessLayer<TEntity> _dataAccessLayer;
        private PropertyInfo _parentProperty;

        public ChainableEntityDataFetcher(IDataAccessLayer<TEntity> dataAccessLayer)
        {
            _dataAccessLayer = dataAccessLayer;
            GetDescendents = DataFetcherAsync;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _dataAccessLayer.Dispose();
            GetDescendents = null;
            _parentProperty = null;
        }

        async Task<ReadOnlyObservableCollection<TEntity>> DataFetcherAsync(TEntity parentEntity,string parentPropertyName)
        {
            var _comparableValue = parentEntity == null ? " is NULL" : " = " + parentEntity.DbModelId.ToString();
            var _dataList = _dataAccessLayer.GetEntities(new Dapper.CommandDefinition(String.Format("select * from {0} where {1}{2}",
                _dataAccessLayer.TableName,
                parentPropertyName,
                _comparableValue)));

            ObservableCollection<TEntity> _entities = new ObservableCollection<TEntity>(_dataList);
            ReadOnlyObservableCollection<TEntity> _readOnlyEntites = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<TEntity>(_entities);

            return _readOnlyEntites;
        }


    }
```

*DataAccessLayer*

```
 public class DataAccessLayer<TEntity> : IDataAccessLayer<TEntity> where TEntity : DbModel
    {
        public IDbConnectionBuilder DbConnectionBuilder { get; }
        private readonly string _tableName;

        ...
        public ICollection<TEntity> GetEntities(CommandDefinition command)
        {
            using (var _connection = DbConnectionBuilder.GetDbConnection())
            {
                _connection.Open();
                return _connection.Query<TEntity>(command).ToList();
            }
        }
        ...
```

#### Screenshots

[image]

Comment: Maybe _connection.Query<TEntity>(command).ToList() is causing memory escalation. Could you see how many rows does query returns. "ToList()" reads all records and create POCOs in memory. 
If that is problem you could return IQUERIABLE from DAL and than read IQUERIABLE in chunks with Enumerator and yield.

Comment: i don't think so it's because of Query<TEntity> one reason is that i tested this element with same Query and it works just fine and no memory problem
problem is after using that element like 7 times it starts to occupy more and more memory even if the system is idle i mean not using the element
i think something is disposing the child element and cause it keep creating sub-elements

Comment: @Al-HanashMoataz I'm facing a similar problem. Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem..
It is with the `async StateHasChanged`
Just don’t use `StateHasChanges` in an async operation